# What is the Feynman Kac Formula for the Merton model

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

I know that for the diffusion process 
$$
dX_t = \mu(t, X_t) dt + \sigma(t, X_t) dB_t,
$$
the function
$$
u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}_{x, t}[e^{\int_t^T r(s, X_s) ds} \phi(X_T)]
$$
with the boundary condition $u(T, x) = \phi(x)$
satisfies (from the Feynman Kac formula)
$$
u_t(t, x) + \mu(t, x)u_x(t, x) + \frac{\sigma^2(t, x)}{2}u_{xx}(t, x) - r(t, x)u(t, x) = 0
$$
with
$u(T, x) = \phi(x)$.

My question is what is the form of the Feynman Kac formula (PDE) if 
$$
dX_t = \mu(t, X_t) dt + \sigma(t, X_t) dB_t + 
(Y_t − 1)dN_t,
$$
where $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda>0$ and $Y_t$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with log-normal distribution.

I'm just starting to learn about jump processes so I do not know how to obtain the PDE for above mentioned $u(t, x)$ function in case of the jump process $X_t$.

Comment: This paper has the formula in the second section: http://www.bbk.ac.uk/ems/for_students/msc_finEng/pricing_emms014p/XmasAssign12.pdf

Comment: Not exactly, I think that they consider $u(x, t) = e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}_{x, t}[F(X_T]$.
Moreover I found similar topic here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140139/feynman-kac-for-jump-diffusion, but they consider compound Poisson process and PDE they obatined differs from this in the link you wrote.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question